# Logstash not sending data to Elasticsearch

Tags: logstash

I have a logstash config which reads nginx logs and sends data to elasticsearch.
The log file contains two endpoints viz `/index` and `/info`. Logstash parses the `/index` endpoint and sends the data to ES but it doesn't do the same with `/info` endpoint.

The issue is that when I run logstash in foreground using `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash` to debug the problem, it is able to parse both the endpoints and send data to ES, whereas as a daemon it does so only with the `/index` endpoint.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, can anybody please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What does logstash logs say? Check it for grokking errors. Also, when you run it in the foreground, do you run it with a root user instead of logstash user? It could be a permissions issue.

Comment: I'm running logstash as root in the background and I've changed the permissions of log file accordingly, so I can safely say that it's not a permission issue. It doesn't give any error in logstash.err, logstash.stdout or logstash.log files either. I've also checked grokparser and on multiple logs in the foreground for grokking errors, but didn't found any.